# cursor jumps, words jumbled (emacs in terminal via iTerm2 on macos)

Tags: osx, cursor

I use GNU Emacs 27.2 on macos (Monterey) in an iTerm2 terminal window.  iTerm2 settings are largely default (I have remapped esc to option as my metakey).

When I open a file and start editing, things are ok for a while, but at some point the cursor seems to become confused.  I believe I can reproduce a case:

- edit a file
- consider a line such as `baz foo  = bar`
- arrow key to a word in the code, in example `bar`
- add a space
- hit backspace
  => cursor now appears under word 7 spaces to the left, under `foo`
- hit spacebar and word under cursor changes to `bar`.  Add two more spaces and save.
- reopen emacs; file now has line `baz foo =    bar` (three spaces added).

I haven't been able to reproduce more, but it does seem that it "gets worse" as I attempt to edit.  There may be other cases.

I have seen other cases where `PS1` setting is salient.  Mine is `\[\033[0;32m\]\w\[\033[0m\]$` but if I `unset PS1` I can still reproduce the issue.

Using gnu bash `GNU bash, version 5.1.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0)`

my `~/.emacs.d/` has only `auto-save-list/` -- I have made no local configuration changes.

Does anyone know what I could look at to figure this out?

Comment: You’re probably setting `TERM` to an inappropriate value, causing Emacs to send the wrong escape sequences for things like cursor motion. Make sure that you’re not setting `TERM` to anything in your shell init files (such as `.bashrc` if you use Bash, etc).

Comment: I'm having the same issue and can't figure it out. It's definitely something related to `iTerm`.  I've found that even with I ignore my rcs with `zsh -f`, initialize a new simple `/bin/sh` shell, or ssh into my location machine, emacs in iTerm has the same issue. However, everything always works when using Terminal.app!  The only way I've gotten the emacs cursor to work correctly in iTerm is from within a `tmux` session. If you've solved this I'd love to hear how!

Comment: update! If I create a new iTerm profile and set its 'Reporting terminal type' value to 'ansi', then everything works! Curiously, setting the iTerm profile this way does more than just change the $TERM env var. Because if I run `XTERM=ansi emacs ...` in a iTerm profile that has terminal type set to `xterm` then emacs open in a weirdly even more broken way. So the key is that setting 'Reporting terminal type' to `ansi` in the iTerm profile is doing something else that's critical.